# Spyder modules work with Conda-Navigator but not with Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I'm a little confused as to what the source of my problem is. I have modules in a python file that I need to import.

I opened up Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3). In the terminal, I tried conda install -[packages], but every time, the install would just break.

So I figured I'd try to manually add those packages through Navigator. The module installs were successful so I closed out of Navigator, opened Anaconda Prompt, launched spyder and tried to import the modules. Did not work.

So then I opened spyder through Navigator. And the modules imported successfully. Can someone explain to me why the modules are successfully imported when I launch Spyder from the Navigator and not when I launch via Anaconda Prompt - and propose a solution so I can just launch via the prompt. As far as I can tell, I'm in the root environment under both cases.

Edit:
When I launch via Navigator the following command window is luanched
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
When I launch via Anaconda Prompt, I have:
Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)

Comment: The pancakes may have installed in different environments.

Comment: Like I said, when I open the CLI for Navigator, its CMD.exe. This may be the problem. So 2 things: Why isn't the CLI for Navigator Anaconda3 Prompt and is there a way to change this? Not even sure if this is the real issue... this is the first time I'm dealing with this problem.

Comment: Did you open the Anaconda Prompt "Run as administrator" or just open when tryin to install the package? I would try either case to see if it will give different results, if not yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the Anacondo Prompt, can you try using pip to install packages and see if that helps?

> pip install [package]

Comment: One of my modules won't install with pip (get an error). That's why I tried installing it through Navigator and it was successful. I always thought Navigator and Anaconda Prompt were the same ie (if you installed a package via prompt, it would show up in Navigator and vice versa)

Comment: That's strange. What did the error message say?

Comment: Error: Command errored out with exit status 1. So when I open the CLI via Navigator, it opens up the windows terminal (CMD.exe). Maybe that's why? Not sure why it's not opening up in Anaconda3 prompt

Comment: You might want to provide the full error message so others can tell  what the problem is...